# Is there any effective & fast way to catch two match in a log file?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I would like to get some ideas.

My situation: there are tons of logs on my Linux server that are big and they are also have tons of things in them. I would like to catch ONLY the login with a timestamp and ONLY the email address from the log and collect them to a .txt file.

An example log:

```
[...]
2019-07-21 03:13:06.939 login 
[things not needed between the two]
(mail=>example@mail.com< method=>email< cmd=>login<)
[...]
```

An example output:

```
************** 2019-07-21 **************
2019-07-21 03:13:06.939 login
example@mail.com
2019-07-21 06:22:19.424 login
example@mail.com
2019-07-21 12:10:23.665 login
example@mail.com
2019-07-21 14:26:19.068 login
example@mail.com

************** 2019-07-22 **************
2019-07-22 08:01:50.157 login
example@mail.com
2019-07-22 08:12:35.504 login
example@mail.com
2019-07-22 09:10:35.416 login
example@mail.com
```

To achieve this I am using this right now:

```
for i in $(ls); do echo "" && printf "************** " && cat $i | head -c 10 && printf " **************\n"; while read line; do echo $line | grep "login"; echo "$line" | grep -h -o -P '(?<=mail=>).*?(?=<)'; done < $i; done >> ../logins.txt
```

The for loop is going through the files, `cat $i | head -c 10` will get the date (because that is the first thing in every log), the while loop is reading the file line-by-line and greps login and ONLY the mail address (grep between "mail=>" "<"). And at the end it is outputting to logins.txt.

While this is working I find it very-very slow because it's executing a lots of commands. (And we are talking about 2 years of logs here) And it is also looks really dirty.

I really think that there is an effective way to do this but I don't really get what would that be.

Comment: Is there a log file per day?

Comment: Your line is too long. If you break it up into several lines, people will have an easier time reading, and you will have a better chance of getting help.

Comment: You should not use an external command for each line in a loop, commands like `awk`, `sed` and `grep` can operate over the whole file.

Comment: @Fravadona Yes there was a log per day and it was 2 years of log 0-24. With my messed up loop it was really slow. But after using sed it was like 100x faster.

Comment: @WalterA You're absolutely right, after the answers I received (from you too) I decided to learn awk and sed to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` use the `-F` for selecting the mail account:

```
sep='************************'
awk -v sep="$sep" -F '(mail=>|<)' '
  FNR==1 { printf("%s %s %s\n", sep, substr($0,0,10), sep)}
  /mail=>/ {print $2}
  /login *$/ {print}
' *
```

When you have additional requirements and want to use a loop, consider

```
for f in *; do
  sed -nr '
    1s/(.{10}).*/********* \1 **********/p;
    /login *$/p;
    s/.*mail=>([^<]*).*/\1/p
  ' "${f}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! The sed one was the right one. It was much faster than my messy one. 
Guess what, I have to learn sed and awk, they are really useful. I bet they are not that hard to use, but for the eyes first it's a bit scary.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` would do a nice job of this. You can tell it to print the line only when  the line matches a particular regex. Something like:

```
 awk '$0~/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|\(mail=>/{print $0}' * > output.log
```

Updated: Noticed you just want the email. In the case, two blocks will suffice. In the second block we split by characters `<` or `>` and then retrieve the email from index 2 of the resulting array.

```
 awk '$1~/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{print $0}$1~/^\(mail=>/{split($1,a,"[<>]");print a[2]}' * > output.log
```

This awk says:

1. If the first field (where the field is delimited by awk's default of a space character) of the row we are reading starts with a date of format `nnnn-nn-nn`: `$1~/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/`
2. Then print the entire line `{print $0}`
3. If the first field of the row we are reading starts with the characters `(mail=>`: `$1~/^\(mail=>/`
4. Then split the first field by either characters `<` or `>` into an array named `a`:  `split($1,a,"[<>]")`
5. Then print the 3rd item in the array (index 2): `print a[2]`
6. For all of the files in this current directory: `*`
7. Instead of printing to the command line, send the output to a file: `> output.log`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanation, it was really useful for me. Looks like it's time to start learning awk and sed. For first it's a bit hard on the eyes tho.